# Computationally efficient way of calculating euclidean distance between points and nearest line on a landscape in R sf

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, euclidean-distance

I have a large dataset of GPS locations (480,476) and a large shapefile of roads (lines; 561487) and I want to efficiently calculate the distance to the nearest road for each point.

If I tried using **st_distance(points_sf, roads_sf)** which calculates a distance matrix: the Euclidean distance between every point in points_sf (1:480476) and every line in roads_sf (1:561487) which was too big. Thus, I split it up into smaller chunks by ID which was more manageable. Even still it took a long time (> 1 day) and took up a lot of memory so that I couldn't run anything else on the computer or risked crashing it (even with 64 GB of RAM).

Is there a more computationally efficient way to do this sort of calculation in R?

Comment: What would the next step be? Do you need to classify points by their distance to closest roads? Do you need to know which road segment is closest? What's the required precision here and are there perhaps some predefined distance bands (I.e. you only want to filter points that are (or are not) within x km from closest road? And what's the area here (city/county/country/continent)? Just trying to get an idea if this is something that could be solved through distance raster.

Answer (score 0):

What I have so far is to use **st_nearest_feature()** to identify the nearest line to each point and then calculate the distance between the point and its nearest line.

This was my solution:

```
    near_rd = st_nearest_feature(points_sf, roads_sf)
    dist_rd = sapply(1:length(near_rd), function(x)
                  st_distance(points_sf[x,], roads_ms[near_rd[x],]))
```

Comment: How long did this approach take to run on your data?

Comment: It's not quite clear if you consider this as an answer (answering your own questions is perfectly fine) or it's more part of your question and you describe what have you tried but it's still too slow?